# Showing Unity3d ads followed by Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to show an interstitial advertisement on an Android application when users choose to replay a current scene in my Unity3d game. My first attempt at doing so produced a flicker of the test advertisement in the editor, but failed to produce anything on an actual device.

Here's the code I used (only relevant code included):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{

    ...

    void Awake ()
        {
            Advertisement.Initialize("Game ID omitted");
        }

    ...

    public void ShowAd ()
    {
        // If ready, show an advertisement
        if (Advertisement.IsReady ()) 
        {
            Advertisement.Show ();
        }
    }

    public void Replay ()
    {
        ShowAd ();

        Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
    }
```

I thought this might have something to do with `Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);` following the `ShowAd ();`, so I created a new test button to try to isolate the issue:

```
public void ShowAd ()
{
    // If ready, show an advertisement
    if (Advertisement.IsReady ()) 
    {
        Advertisement.Show ();
    }
}

public void TestAdButton ()
{
    ShowAd ();
}
```

This displays the ad properly; however, I'd like to implement the ad following a click of the replay button (which should then trigger a replay of the current scene). I'm further confused by the Unity employees stating that [show an add will automatically pause the game](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-do-i-pause-the-game-while-the-ads-are-showing.332757/).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that I am seeing is that you call LoadLevel after calling ShowAd, therefore the add is being shown but then immediately being overriden by LoadLevel. Try having a PlayerPrefs stored to determine whether the level was restarted or not.

```
public void Replay ()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isReplayed", 1);
    Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

Then on the GameController add:

```
public void Start()
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isReplayed") == 1)
    {
         ShowAd();
    }
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isReplayed", 0);
}
```